# KDE mediacontroller hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, media-buttons

My problem: i use Kubuntu 18.04, I would like the music playback from a keyboard to direct, but volumeup and volumedown option is not presented in the global shortcut keys, only play/pause, rewind/forward and stop option.
Help please, how it is possible to solve this?

[image: Kubuntu mediacontroller hotkeys]

Comment: Don't you see something like https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdubG.png ?

Comment: It is properly, but it regulates the capital volume, the media controller though the music player, this I need latter one.

Comment: You can also try asking at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), or [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), or [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/) or [reddit/kubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/).